# Vue.JS 3, Bootstrap 5, Laravel 9 - Modal Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-5, laravel-9

I am building a registration form. It contains a button which opens a Bootstrap 5 modal over the top of the form. I intent to use it to allow the potential user to verify their account ownership.

However, the Modal it doesn't display at all.

**Troubleshooting performed so far**
I have added a console.log to the openmodal method and it's logging correctly.
I have also attempted to load the modal on mount, however this also did not work.

**Code**

```html
<template>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    id="verificationModal"
    ref="verificationModal"
    v-if="showModal"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Verify Summoner Account</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
            @click="closeModal"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>
            Please change your summoner account icon to the following image:
          </p>
          <div class="summoner-icon-container">
            <img
              :src="randomSummonerIcon"
              alt="Random Summoner Icon"
              class="summoner-icon"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="verifySummoner">
            Verify
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-secondary"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            @click="closeModal"
          >
            Close
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Form -->
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input
          v-model="form.username"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="username"
          aria-describedby="usernameHelp"
          placeholder="Enter username"
        />
        <div v-if="errors.username" class="invalid-feedback">
          {{ errors.username[0] }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input
          v-model="form.password"
          type="password"
          class="form-control"
          id="password"
          placeholder="Enter password"
        />
        <div v-if="errors.password" class="invalid-feedback">
          {{ errors.password[0] }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input
          v-model="form.email"
          type="email"
          class="form-control"
          id="email"
          aria-describedby="emailHelp"
          placeholder="Enter email"
        />
        <div v-if="errors.email" class="invalid-feedback">
          {{ errors.email[0] }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="summoner_name">Summoner Name</label>
        <input
          v-model="form.summoner_name"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="summoner_name"
          placeholder="Enter summoner name"
        />
        <div v-if="errors.summoner_name" class="invalid-feedback">
          {{ errors.summoner_name[0] }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        v-if="form.summoner_verified"
        class="btn btn-primary"
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
    <button
      v-if="!form.summoner_verified"
      @click="openModal"
      class="btn btn-secondary"
    >
      Verify Summoner
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from "axios"

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          username: "",
          password: "",
          email: "",
          summoner_name: "",
          summoner_verified: false,
        },
        errors: {},
        showModal: false,
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      $(this.$refs.verificationModal).modal()
    },
    methods: {
      openModal() {
        this.showModal = true
        console.log("Model Opened")
      },
      closeModal() {
        this.showModal = false
        console.log("Model Closed")
      },
      submitForm() {
        axios
          .post("/api/register", this.form)
          .then((response) => {
            // redirect to dashboard or display success message
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors
          })
      },
      verifySummoner() {
        axios
          .post("/api/verify-summoner", {
            summoner_name: this.form.summoner_name,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            this.form.summoner_verified = response.data.summoner_verified
            this.form.rank = response.data.rank

            if (this.form.summoner_verified) {
              this.closeModal()
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you use any CSS to hide/display the modal and forget to reset it?

Comment: @NehaSoni I did not. No custom CSS for the modal, all bootstrap 5 and vue.js to show/ hide the modal

Comment: You have to use Bootstrap's built in JS library or manually add/remove the `show` class on the modal div because the `modal` class is hidden by default.

Comment: You don't have to make a separate function to open a modal. You can just add `data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalID"` to the `button`. Don't forget to put an `id` to your modal